# CSV Writer including [] when when writing multiple variables but not when writing a single list?

Tags: python, csv

I have a script that iterates through a series of files and  extracts data from some x-y co-ordinates from each one.  The extraction works fine and is stored in a variable called 'values'

```
temp = []
    for i in range(0, 999, 25):
        temp.append(i)

    values = (xdata[perc_vals])
```

If I use csv writer to write values to a file it works perfectly

```
    with open('output.csv', mode='a') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(values)
        out_file.close()
```

gives me a row for each file which looks something like:

> 0.0,-0.0865537707149719,-0.3314341934031176,-1.4728130158176487,-3.4660493121130105,-6.210198662089092,-8.361139870938594,-10.03746492495204,-12.61339932907623,-15.11070292589451,-16.583093175661595,-17.512077439632442,-17.997434744970562,-17.648476628885575,-17.09341051993358,-16.326714292361753,-14.800725518936838,-12.263934663769612,-9.756208890109596,-8.506835989820754,

This is how the data should look, and allows it to be opened in other spreadsheets.

The problem is I need so other data from each file on the same row such as the peak value, the time of the peak value and the name of the file it is in.  I each of these stored as their own variable.  If I make a new list with these variables eg.

```
all_data = [file_name, max_value, time_of_max, values]
```

and pass it to csv writer

```
writer.writerow(all_data)
```

The data now includes quotes and square brackets

> Data_File_A1.txt,-17.997434744970562,0.3942942942942943,"[0.0, -0.0865537707149719, -0.3314341934031176, ...... , 0.3902889186740477]"

You can see the file name, max value and time of max from     all data. are outputted correctly, but the values data now has square brackets and quotes.  Including

```
quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' '
```

removes the quotes but leaves the square brackets.

> Data_File_A1.txt,-17.997434744970562,0.3942942942942943,[0.0 ,  -0.0865537707149719 ,  -0.3314341934031176 ,  -1.4728130158176487 ,  -3.4660493121130105 ,  -6.210198662089092 ,  -8.361139870938594 ,  -10.03746492495204 ,  .... ,  0.3902889186740477]

Changing to a tuple

```
all_data = (file_name, max_value, time_of_max, values)
```

does not change the output.

I think it is because it is a list within a list, but I can't see how to add the additional data without making it a list with a list inside?

I guess I could regex through the file to remove the [] but that seems like a hack.  Help greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I am an idiot - the answer was to append the additional data to 'values' so I now have a single list